No puedo abrir Spyder
Desde hace un mes que no se porque no puedo abrir la aplicación Spyder 6 desde mi Windows. Cuando le doy a ejecutar no acaba de función y no me abre. Si miro el administrador de tareas me dice que existe el proceso pero por mucho tiempo que deje no se abre. Antes estaba en Windows 10 y ahora estoy en Windows 11, pero en ambos me sucedida el error. También he intentado abrir spyder mediante anaconda que lo tengo instalado aparte y tampoco me laza la aplicación. Si alguien sabe como ayudarme muchas gracias.

Spider 6 acaba de lanzar una nueva versión (6.0.2).  Es possible que  reinstalándola se solucione el problema.

Conoces las versión especifica de Spider que usas https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases ?
